# random intercept, random slope, what's next?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

Consider a mixed effects model with a **random intercept**. This means

$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij}.$$
Now, suppose that we group the observations with respect to time
$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + b_{1i}t_{ij} + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij}.$$
This is a **random slope** model.

If I use higher orders in the expansion of $t$, what are those models called? This is

$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + b_{1i}t_{ij} + b_{2i}t_{ij}^2 + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij}.$$
...
$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + b_{1i}t_{ij} + b_{2i}t_{ij}^2 + ... + b_{pi}t_{ij}^p + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij}.$$

Comment: It is still a random slopes (and intercepts) model

Comment: As @RobertLong wrote, this is still a random slopes models. I tend to call them *nonlinear random slopes*. Just as a side note, it would be better to work with splines instead of polynomials. These are available in the **splines** package in R; for example, you could use natural cubic splines using function `ns()`.

Answer (score 1):

The models that include random effects for the higher order terms can still be referred to as a random slopes (and intercepts model). They can also be referred to as random **coefficients** (and intercepts) models. The latter is slightly more intuitive:

$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij} \tag{1}$$

$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + b_{1i}t_{ij} + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij} \tag{2}$$

$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + b_{1i}t_{ij} + b_{2i}t_{ij}^2 + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij}\tag{3}$$

$$y_{ij} = b_{0i} + b_{1i}t_{ij} + b_{2i}t_{ij}^2 + ... + b_{pi}t_{ij}^p + \dots \text{  fixed effects } \dots +e_{ij}\tag{4}$$

$(1)$ is a **random intercepts-only model**.

$(2)$ is a **random intercepts and random slopes model** (note that it is possible to have random slopes without random intercepts, so it can be a little confusing to call it just a random slopes model). This makes intuitive sense because each subject has it's own slope for $t$.

$(3)$ and $(4)$ are also a **random intercepts and random slopes models**, however coefficients for the higher order terms control the *shape* of the curve, so they might, more intuitively, be called **random random intercepts, random slopes and random *shapes* models**.

More generally, $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ can be called **random intercepts and random *coefficients* models**

Comment: @Misto does this answer your question ? If so, please can you mark it as the accepted answer...